# Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Product.collections

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The relationship between Product and Collection is many to many. A product can be in many
collections and each collection can have many products. For such case, I want to convert the django models to sqlalchemy in fastapi. Below is a table for product and collection in django models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)


class CollectionProduct(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        "Collection", related_name="collectionproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="collectionproduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        blank=True,
        related_name="collections",
        through=CollectionProduct,
        through_fields=("collection", "product"),
    )
    background_image = VersatileImageField(
        upload_to="collection-backgrounds", blank=True, null=True
    )
```

I tried the below way to migrate django model to sqlalchemy. However, I got following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
> between parent/child tables on relationship Product.collections -
> there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that
> referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or
> ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

sqlalchemy

```
class Product(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    # referencing the parent
    product_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("producttype.id"))
    product_type = relationship("ProductType", back_populates="products")

    collections = relationship(
        "Collection",
        back_populates="product",
    )
    collectionproduct = relationship("CollectionProduct", back_populates="product")



class Collection(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    slug = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    product = relationship(
        "Product",
        # secondary=ProductCollection.__tablename__,
        back_populates="collections",
    )
    collectionproduct = relationship("CollectionProduct", back_populates="collection")


class CollectionProduct(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    collection_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("collection.id"))
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product.id"))

    collection = relationship("Collection", back_populates="collectionproduct")
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="collectionproduct")
```

How can I migrate django models for product and collections in sqlalchemy by overcoming join issue?

Comment: You are defining 2 relationships; one directly between `Product` and `Collection`; and one via `CollectionProduct`. Is should be enough to delete the `product` and `collections` relationships as there is no foreign key linking these tables directly.

Comment: Thank you @rfkortekaas for your comment. Do you mean to say I should remove `collections = relationship(
        "Collection",
        back_populates="product",
    )` field from Product table and `product = relationship(
        "Product",
        # secondary=ProductCollection.__tablename__,
        back_populates="collections",
    )` field from Collection table?

Comment: Yes, you need to access the collection of a product via the CollectionProduct relation!